# Can't unset window shortcut

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, kubuntu, kde

I somehow set konsole to activate an open instance using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> which also happens to be browsers default re-open closed tab shortcut. I want to unset this window shortcut on console but I cannot figure out how to do so.

I've looked through the special window settings, special application settings and could not find anything there. I can temporarily unset the shortcut, listed as "Activate Window (Wallpapers:bash {<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>})", in the global shortcuts but when I restart my computer it will return. I even tried resetting all the global keybindings to default but that did not stick either.

Running:
Kubuntu 12.04.1
 
KDE 4.8.5

Edit:

I've turned off the "New Tab" shortcut, it does not help:
[image]

Here's the option I have to disable to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to stop overriding my browser, however, it resets every time I reboot.

[image]

Comment: Don't choose `none` set one that you don't use like `Ctrl+Shift+L` for example

Comment: I tried that and it also resets it back to Ctrl+Shift+T on reboot. :/

Comment: Are you using 12.04.1? Cause My 12.04.1 doesn't have the **Activate window** option listed like the last screenshot

Comment: Yes it is 12.04.1 and yes it seems I somehow added this as a custom shortcut a while ago (I cannot for the life of me remember) and now I cannot get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you probably set the keyboard shortcut for Konsole from the Kickoff Application launcher icon.

In order to remove this shortcut, right click on the Konsole launcher icon → Edit Applications → System → Konsole → Advanced Tab → Current Shortcut Key → Reset it.

[(Reference)](https://superuser.com/questions/372684/open-kubuntu-terminal-with-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: Seemed promising but no dice :(

Comment: The last choice I can offer is probably [resetting the entire KDE settings.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/109530/how-do-i-restore-my-kde-desktop-to-default)

Answer (score 0):

This shoud be simple.

1. Open Konsole and choose Settings
2. Then choose Keyboard Shortcuts
3. Go to the part: New Page - change that keyboard shortcuts

Comment: This did not help please see my edit for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Konsole bug which resets its shortcuts at the start of the application. Just try this : launch Konsole, change a shortcut using the "Settings > Configure Shortcuts ..." menu, then quit Konsole, and relaunch it. Check the shortcuts in the settings dialog : they are back to their previous value.

Comment: No joy :( I don't have [ctrl]+[shift]+[t] in those settings.