# Clicking link in PDF spawns thousands xdg-open processes

Tags: kde4, xdg-open

I have a PDF with a link to a web page, that used to work (it would open the link in firefox, via xdg-open). However, when I click it now, literally thousands of xdg-open processes are started and plasma-desktop runs at 100% cpu.

I don't know how to start troubleshooting this. What could cause this issue?

An example of a problem PDF is [here](http://hem.eyra.se/tmp/regionsje.pdf).

Here is a screenshot of what happens. Note the corrupted taskbar due to thousands of xdg-open instances
[image: Here is a screenshot of what happens. Note the corrupted taskbar due to thousands of xdg-open instances]

Comment: In which application are zou trying to open it.

Comment: Firefox is my default web browser, so in this case it would be firefox.

Comment: I am using Kubuntu 14.04 and browsed the pdf through firefox and the link opened just fine in my case. Could you please show us a screenshot regarding your issue?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, FF 40.0.3 works as expected. Same if I download and open with evince. Have you tried the latter?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the PDF, but rather with my configuration of KDE, and xdg-open in particular. I've added a screenshot in the question now.

Comment: You could reset your userprofile to default as explained here https://askubuntu.com/questions/109530/how-do-i-restore-my-kde-desktop-to-default to verify your assumption. I cannot recreate this on my KDE machine (this is not Ubuntu however)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the culprit was a bad setting in Dolphin, where the default "open as" action for html files was xdg-open, which I guess caused an infinite loop. After changing the default program to Firefox instead, it works as expected.

I would have thought that having selected Firefox in "System Settings / Default Programs" would have sufficed, but apparently not.

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same issue, but then for opening a `mailto:` link. The approach to debug the problem is probably similar to yours, however.

First, find what handles the mailto (or in your case, http) scheme:

```
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/mailto
kmailservice5.desktop
```

Now, what is `kmailservice5.desktop`?

```
$ locate kmailservice5.desktop
/usr/share/applications/kmailservice5.desktop
```

Opening the above file shows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=kmailservice5 %u
Icon=mail-message-new
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;

X-DocPath=kioslave5/mailto/index.html
NoDisplay=true

# KMailService is the handler for mailto URLs
Name=KMailService
...
```

I wonder what `kmailservice5` does?

```
$ kmailservice5 --help
   xdg-open -- opens a file or URL in the user's preferred
   application

Synopsis

   xdg-open { file | URL }

   xdg-open { --help | --manual | --version }

Use 'man xdg-open' or 'xdg-open --manual' for additional info.
```

This is exactly the same output as `xdg-open --help`! That's weird... I looked up the source of `kmailservice5` and found http://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks5-apidocs/kio/html/kmailservice_8cpp_source.html. It is a simple application that calls `QDesktopServices::openUrl` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl (In KDE4, [the mail application was explicitly invoked via `KToolInvocation::invokeMailer`](http://api.kde.org/4.0-api/apidox-kde-4.0/kdelibs-apidocs/kio/html/kmailservice_8cpp_source.html); My partial upgrade to KDE5 is probably the reason for this breakage).

In other words, mailto:... opens the handler of mailto:, which opens the handler of mailto:, etc. This never ends and the only way to end this loop was to issue `killall kde-open plasma-desktop`.

---

To solve the issue I created a `robs-mailto.desktop` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=kdialog --msgbox "Rob's mailto handler: %u"
Icon=mail-message-new
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;

Name=RobsMailtoHandler
```

and registered it as follows:

```
$ xdg-mime default robs-mailto.desktop x-scheme-handler/mailto
```

and verified that it was correctly registered:

```
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/mailto
robs-mailto.desktop

$ xdg-open mailto:test@example.com
# (opened a KDialog window that printed the email address, as I specified)
```

Comment: OK, I just fixed the --help issue, that was an easy one (http://commits.kde.org/kio/b37a93681ed0de79cd86c39d4aecc49c164a7000). The actual bug is tracked in https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354151 / https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344527, I'll look at that next.

Comment: The mailto: recursion is now fixed (fix will be in KF 5.22). You can apply the fix locally right now: just delete kmailservice5 and PREFIX/share/applications/kmailservice5.desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, don't make xdg-open the preferred application. Because the job of xdg-open *is* to find out the preferred application. Infinite recursion ensues.

In other words, xdg-open is a "client" of the mime/apps preference system.
One has to specify somewhere what actually *is* the preferred application, and that can't possibly be xdg-open itself.

Did you set xdg-open as preferred app for text/html, or was that done by your distro?