# Breeze icon theme wrong icons

Tags: kubuntu, icons, plasma

I could not find this specific issue on Google. After I updated from Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04 LTS, next to xfce4 and unity not working correctly, also the icons from the Breeze icon theme are behaving in an unexpected manner. I have tried to reconfigure and reinstall these packages, however the problem remains.

- Icons such as the Firefox icon are missing
- Instead of the blue folder icon I am seeing a simple flat white icon, this happens as well for icons of files with extensions of images, text, jars, etc.

[image: Here is a screenshot].

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I have a similar problem after updating from Kubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. Folder icons and Firefox don't work. However, for me images have the correct icons. The issue stays if I install the Kubuntu backports.

Comment: I realized that the icon shown for folders actually is a Breeze icon. However, it is this one: `/usr/share/icons/breeze/places/16/folder.svg`. However, for the bigger icons it should change to something like `/usr/share/icons/breeze/places/32/folder.svg` which it does not.

Comment: How to reproduce this? If it can't be reproduced, very few can help

Comment: What is your Desktop Environment? You said Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04, then Xfce4 (how? installed `xubuntu-desktop`on ubuntu?) and saying that Breeze icon is not working, which certainly isn't installed in xubuntu. Please be more clearer about the desktop environment transition

Comment: Happened to me on XFCE and a recreation of the icon cache fixed it. I run `gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/name-of-icon-theme`

Comment: @FabianRost You can look at the workaround I've given in the answer. It worked for me very nicely

Answer (score 2):

This problem was caused by some application from Ubuntu/Unity. In my inspection, it was `appmenu-qt5` which was setting an environment variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME` incorrectly, trying to unify look and feel in GTK and QT. To solve this, we have two options

### Option 1: Remove package `appmenu-qt5`

Just remove the offending package `appmenu-qt5`

```
sudo apt remove appmenu-qt5
```

But, I don't recommend it, if important packages for Unity tries to go away with it. Though, In my case, no other packages was depending on it and simply went away.

### Option 2: Unset the environment variable

You can also unset the environment variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME` to solve this. I recommend this solution.

Put these lines at the end of your `~/.profile` file.

```bash
## Fixing QT problems caused by `appmenu-qt5` in KDE environement
if [ "x$XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP" == "xplasma" ] || [ "x$XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP" == "xKDE" ]; then
    unset QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE
    unset QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the folder icons:
In System Settings -> Applications -> File Associations -> innode -> directory click on the icon. Under System icons choose places and then choose the folder icon from the icons below.

However, that obviously did not change the Firefox icon.

What finally solved all icon problems was to [restore my KDE desktop to default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109530/how-do-i-restore-my-kde-desktop-to-default) via executing

```
mv ~/.kde4 ~/.kde4.old
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same issue. I get over with it using
"**QT5 settings**" program (just search for it, it is already available), changing icon set through its
"**Icon Theme**" settings. It is just easier than changing configuration files. It just works.