# What is causing KDE Plasma icons to get smaller on KDE panel?

Tags: kubuntu, panel, plasma

The space located for the KDE icons and other notification on kde panel suddenly decreases heightwise. Result is there seems to be some space below and above the icons. The only settings I have changed are

1. Changed language settings to be displayed in english than my native
2. Changed all the fonts of kubuntu to ubuntu font.

**Previously:** Notice the icons are bigger and height is enough for time and date. There is also minimal space below the displayed items below and above.

[image]

**Now:** The main height settings for the panel is same, but extra space has been created above and below the icons causing icons to look smaller. Also the time and date now are not displayed on a single line instead of double line for the same main panel height.

*Note:* Height settings for both screenshots are same.

[image]

It has happened multiple times for me. Creating new *default panel* doesn't work. It got me so annoyed that I removed my older user account, and created a new panel where the height was ok. Then I managed my settings for usual programs as before. Everything was looking good. So I decided to backup my home on reboot if the problem arises again. On reboot, viola! The same problem.

I tried these, which didn't work.

- [How do I restore my KDE desktop to default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109530/how-do-i-restore-my-kde-desktop-to-default)
- https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=32445