# Konsole always stays in foreground and retains focus

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, konsole

I recently realized strange behaviors of Konsole. It always stays in foreground and remains the focus.

Examples:

1. I start Konsole. Then, I start Dolphin (or any other application). Dolphin will start but the Window will be behind Konsole. I have to use the task manager to switch to the Dolphin window. I'd expect that Dolphin starts in the foreground.
2. I start Konsole. The I press `Alt+F2` to start KRunner. Krunner appears but immediately disappears. When I type a command, it's typed in Konsole. I'd expect that KRunner appears, stays and that I can run a command.
3. I start Konsole. I click on the Application Launcher in the panel. The application launcher appears. If I now start to type, I would expect that it searches my applications, instead the command is typed in Konsole.

The problem seems to be unique to Konsole. Other applications (I tried Kate and Xterm) do not show this behavior. The behavior of Konsole seems to be new and I cannot remember what I did before it changed. I'm on Kubuntu 16.04.

The `Keep above others` option is **not** activated:

[image: keep above others]

Also the Application Launcher menu appears in front of Konsole. It would appear behind Konsole if the `Keep above others` option would be used.

What can I do to make Konsole behave as I expect?

Comment: What happens when you reset (just to narrow down the problem) your kde profile as described in the answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/109530/how-do-i-restore-my-kde-desktop-to-default...(you  can revert later)

Comment: That fixes the problem.

Comment: That is nice. So you can now restore the backup, excluding everything related to konsole....I dont know exactly which files these are...

Comment: I'm happy with the default profile, so I won't restore anything. If you write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to include the solution you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have enabled Keep Above others via right click --> more actions on the window border

The image below shows dolphin, but the option is available for all windows.

[image]

If this does not help, you could reset your kde profile by running:

```
mv ~/.kde4 ~/.kde4.old
```

Comment: The `Keep above others` option is not ticked. I updated the question accordingly.