# Kubuntu 17.04 : KDE not loading fully?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 17.04

I have just upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10 then 17.04 through the system upgrades method and after logging in, I get a black screen and my mouse cursor once the KDE loading finishes.

Normally there used to be a wallpaper, a taskbar at the bottom, and I could use `alt+f1` to open the KDE search for application and/or files.

I can still control the system using a terminal(ie open system settings or chromium) with my `ctrl+alt+t` shortcut to open one, however I would like to recover KDE to a working state and I can't find a dupliate that would fix this since I don't primarily use the console for everything and don't know a lot of the commands.

If it helps, I  have an Intel processor and graphics card

Comment: First try this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/109530/how-do-i-restore-my-kde-desktop-to-default . If that fails boot a 17.04 live flash drive and if that works more likely then not you should just reinstall. Back up your data first.

Comment: well... I couldn't do it that way but the solution was correct - I had to delete the plasma folders in `.config` folder to reset the KDE 5 Plasma settings. Thanks a lot! That just leaves you to write this as an answer  so I can tick it I guess

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal or using `Alt + F2` execute the command `plasmashell` to start the interface.

You may also try reinstalling the desktop environment by running the command `sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop --reinstall` from the terminal (`Konsole` in KDE Plasma).

Do respond with the results.

Comment: That will not work as the problem is with old configuration files in $HOME and purge / reinstall will not fix this problem.

Comment: Do you think you can explain this a bit more so I can have a better understanding of the situation?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package . As you can see also in the comments "I had to delete the plasma folders in .config folder to reset the KDE 5 Plasma settings" so --reinstall does not delete or update settings in $HOME/.config

Comment: oh, I thought you were referring to an issue with the $HOME directory.

Comment: Yes, configuration files in the home directory are not deleted or updated by purging or reinstalling programs so , unlike windows, you can not fix configuration settings by reinstalling programs in Ubuntu. apt-get remove leaves system files , you have to purge to remove system config files.

Comment: The `plasmashell` via `Alt + F2` was exactly what I needed to get working again with the UI. And even after shutting down the computer, and starting up again, it's working like normal without that command. (Shutting down and starting up didn't do anything before running that command). Thanks!! I'm running 18.04 btw.