# Can I reset Kbuntu desktop

Tags: system

Made a mess of the Kbuntu desktop anyway of resetting it?

Have gone to settings and tried to resize the ikons but it didn't work. Tried the  ikon in the top right and that setting worked. Now the menu has lost the ikon setting and the panel has disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109530/how-do-i-restore-my-kde-desktop-to-default) 
The solution is as follows.

1. logout your kde desktop
2. open console session by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
3. give username and password
4. `rm -rf .kde/share/config/plasma-*`
5. now you can logout console session by logout command or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
6. now go back to your default graphical session by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>
7. now login and you will see your fresh new default panels